# How to pass a css % parameter in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The context for this: [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ruFrp/5/)

I'm trying to make it so the changeWidth function's second parameter can be a percentage value (like in css: `something: 50%;`). If you follow the link I provided it should be fairly obvious why I'm trying to do this. I thought maybe the parameter passed is just a number (e.g. 75), but then in the method itself it converts it to a % for use in the animate(..) invocation... But I don't know how to do this either.

Any ideas? :)

EDIT: I managed it! Don't worry! (If interested, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ruFrp/8/))!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like this:

```
changeWidth($("#testbar"), '50%');
```

it does work for me.

Comment: I'll give you the selected answer as you were first, but I actually managed to work it out before you responded. Thanks anyway though! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the width as a string

```
$(function(){
    changeWidth($("#testbar"), '70%');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ruFrp/7/

```
$(function(){
    changeWidth($("#testbar"), '50%');
});
```